# Next.js renders blank screen in Safari due to Typescript enums

Tags: reactjs, typescript, safari, next.js, yarn-workspaces

The website works fine in Chrome and Edge but not in Safari (for iOS).

It loads all the elements, styling, and scripts but **nothing is displayed.**

After several hours of debugging, turns out it's due to an enum import (not any specific one). I know this because **when I remove the import everything starts to work just fine.**

I'm working in a mono repo (using Yarn workspaces) and all the enums are located in a "shared" package. Importing a class from this "shared" package that already implements the enum works fine, however, **importing any enum directly into the web app causes the issue.**

```
// @*/shared

// ./enums/Protocol.ts

export enum Protocol {
  ETHEREUM = 'ETHEREUM'
}

// ./index.js

...
export * from './enums';
export * from './types';
export * from './utils';
...

// @*/web

// ./modules/api/ApiClient.ts

import { Protocol } from '@*/shared'; // This does NOT work


// Here's an example that implements the enum indirectly.


// @*/shared

import { Protocol } from '../enums';

export class Wallet {
  protocol: Protocol;
}

// @*/web

// ./components/User.tsx

import { Wallet } from '@*/shared'; // This works
```

If the same enum is defined locally, in the "web" package (no import), that also works.

```
// @*/web

// ./modules/api/ApiClient.ts

enum Protocol {
  ETHEREUM = "ETHEREUM"
}

class ApiClient {
  getWallet(protocol: Protocol, address: string) {
    ... // Also works
  }
}
```

No errors are displayed whatsoever, hence I'm really struggling to find out what the issue is. Also, as aforementioned, this issue is only present in Safari.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I learnt that importing (and actually using) anything from that "shared" package caused the issue. The reason behind this was an unsupported regex (lookbehind is still not supported by Safari).

To summarise: importing **anything** from a package that exports a malformed/unsupported regex will cause an issue.